# How to log AWS Fargate container console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions

I have a Cloudformation template with a StepFunction Task for a Fargate container without logging.

I would like to log the console output of this container each time the StepFunction is invoked.

Here is my current Stepfunction definition using Cloudformation,
I would like to add awslogs in this template:

```json
{
"StartAt": "Fargate", 
 "Fargate": {
         "Type": "Task",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
         "ResultPath":"$.ecsResponse",
         "Parameters": {
            "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
            "Cluster": "arn:aws:<CLUSTER_NAME>",
            "TaskDefinition": "<TASK_NAME>",
            "Overrides": {
                "ContainerOverrides": [
                  {
                     "Name": "<CONTAINER_NAME",
                     "Environment": [
                      .......
                     ]
            },
            "NetworkConfiguration": {
               "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
                  "Subnets": [
                    .....
                  ],
                  "SecurityGroups": [
                    ......
                  ],
                  "AssignPublicIp": "ENABLED"
               }
            }
         }
    }
.....
```

Comment: Inside the task definition, you should configure the ECS task to log to CloudWatch Logs. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/centralized-container-logs-with-amazon-ecs-and-amazon-cloudwatch-logs/

Comment: Hi Mark going to try that. Thanks
Any idea if it is possible to get it by default instead having to configure it for each task ?

Comment: No, you have to  configure it for each task.